# Why .net program on linux under mono fails to run?

Tags: linux, mono, delphi-prism, oxygene

I ran my Delphi-prism (.NET) program on Linux under Mono. It ran for awhile and crashed with the following error message on the terminal. But the same program runs perfectly fine on Windows 7

Can anyone tell me why?

```
Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at System.Windows.Forms.XEventQueue+PaintQueue.Dequeue () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUIX11.GetMessage (System.Object queue_id, System.Windows.Forms.MSG& msg, IntPtr handle, Int32 wFilterMin, Int32 wFilterMax) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.XplatUI.GetMessage (System.Object queue_id, System.Windows.Forms.MSG& msg, IntPtr hWnd, Int32 wFilterMin, Int32 wFilterMax) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunLoop (Boolean Modal, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run (System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run (System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Millennia.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/Debugging. Nobody guarantees that any .NET program can run on Mono.

Comment: @LexLi, But it is how Microsoft sold their .NET to the public - compile once and run it anywhere. :) Isn't that in itself a guarantee from Microsoft themselves?

Comment: Microsoft is not SUN. It never says compile once and run it anywhere. Please don't misunderstand that company :)

Comment: But the idea is the same along the line of WORA. Just like SUN's slogan, you can use .NET framework to program in any Microsoft certified programming languages and run it using CLI. Isn't inter-operability mean the same thing as WORA somewhat? In fact, I've read somehwhere that the idea for .NET came from SUN's compile once and run anywhere idea.

Comment: You completely get it wrong. When Microsoft stated .NET is cross platform, it meant a .NET app runs on all **Windows** versions with .NET Framework installed. And that has been fulfilled by Microsoft. On the other hand, one of Mono's goals is to make Linux development easier with C# and CLR. Porting .NET apps to Mono is not of high priority.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your program is using Windows Forms.  Support for Windows Forms is not the best in mono.  Mono provides the runtime and libraries, but if you want to make a cross-platform program you need to consider the UI libraries you make use of as well.

**Update (2016):**

My original answer is probably wrong.  According to [this page](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/), support for Windows Forms 2.0 is complete, but there may still be a number of bugs, I haven't tried it.  However if you use a third-party UI library, for example Infragistics, they probably won't work due to native calls.

Have a look at [this page](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/porting-winforms-applications/) for more info on porting Winforms apps, including the tool MoMA that can help.

Comment: This assertion is IMHO improper. There are many projects written in WinForms running successfully on Mono, including many commercial products (such as JArchitect). So only debugging can reveal the culprit. Rewriting the UI using GTK# or Qt might be an option, but it requires a lot of efforts.

Comment: @LexLi well, on one hand I'd agree with you — rewrite a GUI is not a good idea if you have a big product already. On the other hand, at least, Qt,  much more advanced toolkit, than WinForms. WinForms didn't even have primary selection implemented, to begin with! And I'm not saying of a usual things, like «Ctrl+Backspace» to delete text in widgets, scroll with middle mouse button, etc.

Comment: @Hi-Angel that comment was made years ago. Current status is similar, that no ring to rule them all. Developers can choose any frameworks that meet the needs, while xwt and Eto.Forms gain some popularity. Qt of course can be used if you like, but consider the bad experience I have with Perforce, personally I try to avoid it.

Comment: @LexLi I'm not sure what did they do in Perforce *(didn't even see that app)*, but as someone who worked both with Qt *(not in C# though)* and WinForms *(in C#)*, I'm just  saying facts: there's a bunch of trivia which for some reason didn't work in WinForms, like what I just mentioned. Can't say anything though about xwt and Eto.Forms, as its the first time I hear of them.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Perforce client app is based on Qt so that it runs cross platform, but it looks ugly and does not fit in well with the different operating systems.

Comment: @LexLi well, Skype, for that matter, is written in Qt. Does it look bad? I'd rather guess Perforce are using some ugly theme.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (.net, Linux, Mono).
My program has a provider-subsrciber pattern. The provider is on another thread. 
The main form is subscribed to the provider. When it is fired:

```
    private void RefreshLabels(ParameterMap pm)
    {
        string StateValueKey = string.Empty;
        string svkValue = string.Empty;

        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            BeginInvoke(new RefreshItemsDelegate(RefreshLabels), new object[] { pm });
        }
        else
        {
```

.....
it comes across from the other thread and does its job.

Another subscriber fired an event on the main form also. I ignored this event and the problem DISAPPEARED.